# Advance all elements in a Range in Swift?

Tags: swift, range

If I have a Range, say

```
let bilbo = ( 1 ... 5 )
```

And I wanted to advance all elements of it by a number, say 3, is there a way other than

```
let offset = 3
let baggins = ( bilbo.first! + offset ... bilbo.last! + offset )
```

Something like

```
bilbo.advance_by( 3 )
```

Which I discovered only works for one element in the Range?

I have searched the web and SO and can't find an answer. I'm guessing that there is a Swift-ish way to do this that probably appears in another SO post somewhere that I just don't comprehend how it connects yet. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
let advanceRangeBy : (Range<Int>, Int) -> Range<Int> = { $0.0.first!.advancedBy($0.1) ... $0.0.last!.advancedBy($0.1) }

let bilbo = 1...5
let bagger = advanceRangeBy(bilbo, 3) // 4..<9
```

You can also make it a generic extension to Range that will work for many (although not all) types of Range:

```
let bilbo = 1...5

extension Range where Element : BidirectionalIndexType {
    func advanceRangeBy(advance: Element.Distance) -> Range<Element> {
        return first!.advancedBy(advance) ... last!.advancedBy(advance)
    }
}

let baggins = bilbo.advanceRangeBy(3)
```

---

For the sake of completeness, I thought I'd add that you can also perform this range advancement/de-advancement operation using a custom binary infix operator

```
infix operator <> {
    associativity left
    precedence 140     /* use same precedence as '+', '-' arithmetic */
}
func <> (lhs: Range<Int>, rhs: Int) -> Range<Int>{
    var out : Range<Int> = lhs
    out.endIndex = lhs.endIndex + rhs
    out.startIndex = lhs.startIndex + rhs
    return out
}

let bilbo = 1...5
let bagger = bilbo <> 3    // 4..<9
let frodo = bagger <> (-2) // 2..<7
```

Comment: I'd probably make it an extension on Range @dfri.

Comment: Edited to add the extension option so that my prior (slightly incorrect) answer can be preserved.

Comment: @DavidBerry You're right, you beat me to it. Thanks for that! (Re-edited some spaces for consistency between our two code blocks)

Comment: And @KoCMoHaBTa's answer will even allow the extension to work for all Range's

Comment: I'd probably just use "+" for the operator, but yeah

Answer (score 3):

How about a simple extension:

```
extension Range {

       public func advancedBy(n: Element.Distance) -> Range<Element> {
    
       let startIndex = self.startIndex.advancedBy(n)
       let endIndex = self.endIndex.advancedBy(n)
    
       return Range(start: startIndex, end: endIndex)
    }
}
```

Update for swift 5:

```
public extension CountableRange {
    func advanced(by n: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        
        let lowerBound = self.lowerBound.advanced(by: n)
        let upperBound = self.upperBound.advanced(by: n)
        
        return .init(uncheckedBounds: (lowerBound, upperBound))
    }

    static func + (lhs: Self, rhs: Bound.Stride) -> Self {
        lhs.advanced(by: rhs)
    }
}
```

Note that CountableRange is just a typealias for [Range with conditions](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/countablerange):

```
typealias CountableRange<Bound> = Range<Bound> where Bound : Strideable, Bound.Stride : SignedInteger
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, @KoCMoHaBTa. Tested and works.

Answer (score 1):

Use map:

```
let bagger = bilbo.map { $0.advancedBy(3) }
```

Comment: The bottom line answer to any question that starts with "how can I turn X into Y by iterating over each element of X" is going to be "use map"

Comment: Perfect, @DavidBerry. I had a feeling that it was something like that. Any idea why someone downvoted this? I asked a legitimate question and put some work into making it as clear as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure really, the close indicates that somebody felt there wasn't enough information the question.

Comment: Not that `bagger` is now an array of integers an no longer a `Range<Int>`.

Comment: @DavidBerry, you clearly had enough information to answer the question :) Your abstraction in the answer was highly useful as well.

Comment: @DavidBerry I dabbled myself with this exact map some 10 minutes ago, but left it after that inquiry :) Note that I did not downvote this, I believe in comments rather than ever downvoting stuff by driveby

Comment: Well, as pointed out by @dfri, I didn't really answer it though, depending on what you really wanted.  I've changed the result from a  `Range<Int>` to `[Int]`

Comment: I saw both, @DavidBerry, and appreciate both answers, now quite workable :)